# Remove default language prefix from URL in Drupal 7

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have started to create a website using Drupal 7. I have website to use multi-language functionality. How do I remove default language prefix from URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the language prefix for an enabled language by going to *Configuration > Regional and language > language* and then pressing *edit* on the desired lanaguage.  On edit form you can edit *Path prefix language code* and *save language*.

[image]

**NOTE:** english by default does not have a prefix, other languages should have a prefix if you are using *URL* as a *detection method* in `admin/config/regional/language/configure`.  *URL detection method* is customary to be used in multilingual sites or you might end up with same paths for translated pages (i.e. `/contact` in english `/contact` in french)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.My default language is Arabic.I have made empty path prefix for default language.But it's getting page not found.Is there any solution?

Comment: Drupal 7 still has some kinks when it comes to i18n, I would put default language english with prefix `en` and Arabic with no prefix.  You can get people to visit the correct language frontpage based on their their browser language using `detection method: browser` in Detection and selection configuration page.  My experience says that if english is NOT the default language lots problems arise from core modules and especially from contrib modules.